# Bedikat Chametz and Shehecheyanu

Tags: passover, shehecheyanu, bedikas-chametz

Why is there no *bracha* of *shehecheyanu* recited when performing *bedikat chametz*, unlike other seasonal *mitzvot* (e.g. *shofar*, *lulav*, Chanukah lights, *megillah*)?

Comment: Perhaps *Shehechiyanu* is said only for positive mitzvoth. Granted while there is a mitzvah of "destroying" chametz, I'm uncertain if that's a specific positive mitzvah per se, or it's just a means to perform the negative mitzvah of not having chametz.

Comment: @DanF Fair point. I would point out though that there seems to be some sort of positive mitzvah going on here (possibly rabbinic). Otherwise I’m not sure whether there would be a bracha of al biur chametz.

Comment: Some *did* have *shehecheyanu* on this: the *Hagahot Maymuniyyot* (ברכות פי״א ס״ק ב) says that Shmuel ben Ḥofni HaKohen said it.

Comment: @DanF See the Meiri that I quote in my answer below. He seems to say something very similar to what you suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Taame Haminhagim* (487–489) cites a few reasons:

- (from the *Tur* 432) because the search is for the holiday so the holiday's benediction covers it
- (from *Avudraham*) because we say that benediction only on something that brings joy and physical pleasure, whereas the destruction of one's food brings anguish
- (from *P'ri M'gadim* [*MZ*] 472:end of 2) because you're destroying something

Answer (score 4):

msh210's excellent answer led me to two other reasons:

**Ba'al HaIttur** (quoted in [Tur 432](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Orach_Chaim.432.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) presents an opinion that *shehecheyanu* is not recited because *bedikat chametz* is not strictly seasonal. If one leaves home many months before Pesach and intends to return to his house during Pesach, he must carry out *bedikat chametz* before he leaves. Thus *bedikat chametz* is not necessarily tied to a specific date.

**Meiri** on Pesachim 7a [writes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36400&st=&pgnum=16):

> ונראה לי שמצוה שאין עיקרה לעצמה אלא להרחקת עבירה כגון בדיקת חמץ שהיא ליזהר ממציאת חמץ אין בה זמן
>
> It seems to me that a *mitzva* whose purpose is not for itself, but rather to make a transgression less likely - such as *bedikat chametz* which is for [the purpose of] being careful to avoid finding *chametz* [on Pesach] - has no *shehecheyanu*.

[This answer of the Meiri is very similar to that suggested by DanF in his comments to the OP.]